# How to manage the OCLogger file?

Tags: objective-c, logging, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm debugging a hybrid Worklight (6.1.0.01) application in Xcode (5.1.1).  I'm seeing the following message in my log:

> [DEBUG] [OCLogger] Max file size exceeded for log messages.

I"m assuming that this log file is managed by Worklight, as I do not have any custom native code running or explicit references to OCLogger.  I do have calls to WL.Logger.debug.

How can I manage this log file?  And where is it on my file system?  (Truncating it will probably do the trick at this point.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enabled by default. But you can disable using native or Javascript API Calls.

`[OCLogger setCapture: NO];`

For more info [client side log capture](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_client-side_log_capture.html&resultof%3D%2522%256f%2563%256c%256f%2567%2567%2565%2572%2522%2520%2522%256f%2563%256c%256f%2567%2567%2522%2520)

[client side logging in client apps](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_using_client_log_capture.html&resultof%3D%2522%256f%2563%256c%256f%2567%2567%2565%2572%2522%2520%2522%256f%2563%256c%256f%2567%2567%2522%2520)

Comment: Good to know.  But where is the log file stored on the file system at run-time in development?

Comment: when log capture is enabled. All the values are passed through `NSLog` only to record the logs. To know more about `OCLogger` see this [PDF](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/wl_objcref_ios.pdf)

Comment: I guess because of OCLogger is using `NSLog` it will be in your Documents folder of your app in file system.

Comment: Yes, I found wl.log in the Documents folder of the app sandbox. Deleting the app deleted the log file.